# Error: Call to undefined method ComposerAutoloaderInit13c2409cfa32d1fa0c04493c0d85c93c::getLoader()

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php

I transfer Laravel to VPS and get the following error:

```
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined method ComposerAutoloaderInit13c2409cfa32d1fa0c04493c0d85c93c::getLoader() in /var/www/site.ru/application/vendor/autoload.php on line 7
Error: Call to undefined method ComposerAutoloaderInit13c2409cfa32d1fa0c04493c0d85c93c::getLoader() in /var/www/site.ru/application/vendor/autoload.php on line 7
```

PHP 7.4

I do composer dump-autoload and still no changes

Please help!)

```
git clone ...
composer install
```

Don't work.

Remove vendor and

```
composer install
```

Don't work.

Comment: Hi, have you tried removing/renaming the `vendor` folder and do a fresh `composer install`?

Comment: Hi! Yes, I tried, nothing has changed(

Comment: Thats sad. Maybe it is referred by laravel's own(old) cache. Maybe try a `php artisan cache:clear`?

Comment: I already tried it, it doesn't work

Comment: Maybe a tip: You can add everything you already tried ;) This helps both yourself and us :D

Answer (score 2):

For my case, `symfony server:start` and `php -S` both get the undefined method errors. I've `uopz` installed for testing. Disable the extension, and the error goes.

Answer (score 2):

You have to disable `uopz` extension and restart apache :

```
phpdismod uopz
systemctl reload apache2
```

Answer (score -1):

1 - you need to update php to a newer version (php 7.4.3 or above)

2 - use the composer from the official site (it's better to download it as a file)

In my case, everything worked the first time. I have Linux Mint 20, php 7.4.3, Laravel 7

If you have Linux Mint 20, then to install php7.4.3 you need to change mirros in Software Sources. In my case, I disable the repository from ondrej/php and changed mirros. Next install php